# SSD Wear-Level (SMART value E9) reduced after ATA Secure Erase

Tags: ssd, storage

I have a M.2 Intel 540s SSD with 240 GB of capacity. After 2 years since its first run I did an [ATA Secure Erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) to make sure every cell is deleted (In reality it just deleted the encryption key and generated a new one because it's a SED SSD, I guess) before I reinstall Windows. But now the Wear-Level has become 11%, from initial 28% before the ATA Secure Erase. I'd like to ask how this is possible?

Comment: Went looking in https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P00004908GjSAI/here-is-the-way-to-simply-an-securely-erase-any-drive-ssd-hdd-?language=en_US and other Intel forums, did not find any explanation of this phenomenon. Suggest you post your question there as well.